# ngClass variable change but class stay the same

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have the following ->

```
<li ng-repeat="statusBox in $ctrl.statusListForDisp"
    ng-class="[{'active': statusBox.isActive}, 'label-status-{{statusBox.color}}']"
    layout="column" layout-align="center start">
```

it work great when I load the item for the first time,

[image]

but, if I edit the object, the ngClass is update but not the class itself ->

[image]

is my ngClass syntax wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with using interpolated syntax for the CSS class name.

When this CSS class name changes in the template, AngularJS doesn't consider it a change to the value being passed to `ng-class`, which is why nothing is happening.

Below I've made a minimal example demonstrating the behaviour you're seeing and an alternative which is what you probably want.

Notice that in the alternative, the CSS class name is created using string concatenation.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function () {
    this.statusListForDisp = [
      { color: 'red' },
    ];
    this.makeGreen = function (statusBox) {
      statusBox.color = 'green';
    };
  });
```

```css
.label-status-green { color: green; }
.label-status-red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div
  ng-app="app"
  ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li
      ng-repeat="statusBox in $ctrl.statusListForDisp"
      ng-class="['label-status-{{statusBox.color}}']"
      ng-click="$ctrl.makeGreen(statusBox)">click me: {{ statusBox.color }}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li
      ng-repeat="statusBox in $ctrl.statusListForDisp"
      ng-class="['label-status-' + statusBox.color]"
      ng-click="$ctrl.makeGreen(statusBox)">click me: {{ statusBox.color }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```